# Saving UIColor to RLMObject subclass

Tags: realm

Does Realm support UIColors?

How does one go about adding a UIColor property to a subclass of RLMObject, and what is the recommended method for doing so?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Realm does not directly support reading and writing `UIColor` objects.

That being said, it should be relatively easy to convert a `UIColor` to a format that *can* be saved to Realm, and then convert it back again on demand.

There's no officially recommended way, but the way I would recommend is to convert the `UIColor` to its hexadecimal version, and save it as a string to the Realm object.

There are many libraries on GitHub for performing `UIColor` to hexadecimal conversions, such as this one: https://github.com/nicklockwood/ColorUtils

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I created a superclass which allows any NSObject that supports NSCoding to be saved as a Data object in realm.

```
class RLMArchiveableObject : Object {
    dynamic var data: Data?

    var object: Any? {
        get {
            return (data == nil) ? nil : NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data!)
        }
        set {
            data = (newValue == nil) ? nil : NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newValue!)
        }
    }

    override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["object"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you just need to convert color to string and save that string to realm

```
extension UIColor {
     func toString() -> String {
          let colorRef = self.cgColor
          return CIColor(cgColor: colorRef).stringRepresentation
     } 
 }
```

Comment: then how to use this stored String ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the desired result by adding three float values to the subclassed RLMObject representing the RGB values of the UIColor.

For those having similar problems, I have included my solution below.

### Interface File

```
@interface LFKColor : RLMObject

@property NSString *name;

@property float redColor;
@property float blueColor;
@property float greenColor;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *color;

@end
```

### Implementation File

```
@implementation LFKColor

@synthesize color;

+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
  return @"name";
}

+ (NSArray *)ignoredProperties {
  return @[@"color"];
}

-(void)setColor:(UIColor *)selectedColor {

  self->color = selectedColor;

  const CGFloat* components = CGColorGetComponents(selectedColor.CGColor);
  self.redColor = components[0];
  self.greenColor = components[1];
  self.blueColor = components[2];
}

-(UIColor *)color {
  return [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:self.redColor green:self.greenColor blue:self.blueColor alpha:1.0];
}

@end
```